# C++ Build File for Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++11, sublimetext3

I found a build system for c++ for st3 and it is pretty good but there is a small kink it does not compile unless a .exe file with the source file name exists in the directory. Any idea on how to automate it with the build to create a file if it does not exist or continue?

```
"windows":
{
"cmd": ["g++", "$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall", "&","start", "${file_base_name}.exe"]
},
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should run regardless, as the build will create a .exe file with the source name in the current directory. If for some reason it isn't working, remove everything on line 2 after `"-Wall"` so that it looks like this:

```
"windows":
{
"cmd": ["g++", "$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall"]
},
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```